# Android TalkBack how to override radio button ticked or not ticked

Tags: android, radio-button, talkback

I have problem overriding radio button , i need to disable talkback saying ticked or not ticked ( status of radio button )  can any one know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the built in, RadioButton control, you cannot.  This is the way it will announce.

What you could do is build your own radio button control, with groupings, layouts, and imagebuttons.  But, going through all of this trouble, to make your app less accessible, seems a bit silly to me.